PyScript не работает в HTML
Всем привет, второй день пытаюсь импортировать скрипт питона в хтмл.
Суть такая, у меня есть скрипт проверки актуального курса биткоина, он запускается, все хорошо.
Дальше я захотел добавить его на сайт. Узнал про PyScript, Bryton, но выбрал первый.
И тут самое интересное, открывается пустая страница, смотрю консоль - есть ошибки, но как их решить вообще без понятия. Стоит отметить, что я только начинаю изучать программирование, по этому прошу объяснять популярным языком. спасибо за внимание и ответы
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>testing</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.8.1/core.css">

    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.8.1/core.js"></script>

</head>


    
    <body>
        <script type="text/python" src="/python/bitcoin-rate.py></script>
    </body>
    
</html>

Python:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Currency:
    BTC_URL_RUB = 'https://www.google.ru/search?q=btc+rub&newwindow=1&sca_esv=b39c937a77fb6461&sca_upv=1&ei=2kXjZrD5F8uswPAPjcT52Ak&ved=0ahUKEwiwzv7Elr6IAxVLFhAIHQ1iHpsQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=btc+rub&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiB2J0YyBydWIyCxAAGIAEGLEDGIMBMgoQABiABBhDGIoFMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIGEAAYFhgeSNBMUMkvWPZJcAN4AZABAJgBQaAB6QKqAQE3uAEDyAEA-AEBmAIKoALBA8ICChAAGLADGNYEGEfCAg0QABiABBiwAxhDGIoFwgIOEC4YgAQYsQMY0QMYxwHCAhMQLhiABBixAxjRAxhDGMcBGIoFwgILEC4YgAQY0QMYxwHCAggQLhiABBixA8ICCBAAGIAEGLEDwgILEC4YgAQYsQMYgwHCAh0QLhiABBixAxjRAxjHARiXBRjcBBjeBBjgBNgBAcICEBAAGIAEGLEDGEMYgwEYigXCAg0QABiABBixAxhDGIoFwgIVEAAYgAQYsQMYQxiDARiKBRhGGIICwgIhEAAYgAQYsQMYQxiDARiKBRhGGIICGJcFGIwFGN0E2AEBwgIHEAAYgAQYCpgDAIgGAZAGCroGBggBEAEYFJIHAjEwoAfELQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp'
    BTC_URL_USD = 'https://www.google.ru/search?q=btc+rate+dollar&newwindow=1&sca_esv=b39c937a77fb6461&sca_upv=1&ei=jEXjZr3ONNLUwPAPufXxyQ8&ved=0ahUKEwi9xIKglr6IAxVSKhAIHbl6PPkQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=btc+rate+dollar&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiD2J0YyByYXRlIGRvbGxhcjIHEAAYgAQYEzIIEAAYExgWGB4yCBAAGBMYFhgeMggQABgTGBYYHjIIEAAYExgWGB4yCBAAGBMYFhgeMggQABgTGBYYHjIIEAAYExgWGB4yCBAAGBMYFhgeMggQABgTGBYYHkj2QVCMBlj_PnACeAGQAQCYAVSgAYkDqgEBN7gBA8gBAPgBAfgBApgCCaAC0QPCAgoQABiwAxjWBBhHwgIGEAAYFhgewgIIEAAYgAQYogTCAgUQIRigAcICCBAAGBMYBxgewgIKEAAYExgFGAcYHsICChAAGBMYBxgIGB7CAgYQABgHGB7CAggQABgHGAoYHsICBRAAGIAEwgIKEAAYgAQYQxiKBZgDAIgGAZAGCJIHATmgB_Ej&sclient=gws-wiz-serp'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 .......'}

    full_page_rub = requests.get(BTC_URL_RUB, headers=headers)
    full_page_usd = requests.get(BTC_URL_USD, headers=headers)

    soup_rub = BeautifulSoup(full_page_rub.content, 'html.parser')
    soup_usd = BeautifulSoup(full_page_usd.content, 'html.parser')

    convert_rub = soup_rub.findAll('span', {'class': 'pclqee'})
    convert_usd = soup_usd.findAll('span', {'class': 'pclqee'})
    
    
    print('1 BTC =', convert_usd[0].text,'USD -->',convert_rub[0].text, 'RUB')

Выхлоп


где объявлена функция brython?

Это всё равно работать не будет, потому что google.ru не позволит делать запросы к себе со сторонних сайтов

@andreymal, {mode: 'no-cors'} может помочь, но не факт.

@Qwertiy, ты же так все равно Данные не получишь?

@Grundy, я же написал "Узнал про PyScript, Bryton, но ВЫБРАЛ первый.". я сейчас пытаюсь через PyScript сделать

@andreymal так там запрос идет через юзер агент, т.е через человека

@noname, но в коде у тебя остались следы от второго - они и мешают ¯\(ツ)/¯

@noname изменение юзер-агента никак не повлияет на тот факт, что проверку CORS вы не пройдёте

@Grundy, убрал, не работает

@andreymal есть ли варианты сделать что то с этим?

@noname CORS придумали специально для того, чтобы сделать с этим было ничего нельзя

@andreymal , а можно ещё как-то реализовать эту идею?

@noname ну тогда нужно начинать с самого начала - какую идею-то? Например, у идеи "хочу получить курс бетховенов" есть стопицот разных способов реализации, в том числе без участия питона и гугла вообще

После убирания ошибки из вопроса уже не будет - отредактируй вопрос так, чтобы он отражал проблему

@andreymal
идея сделать курс биткоина на сайте, без готовых виджетов и сделать его максимально "независимым". лучшее что мне пришло в голову это написать скрипт, который парсит гугл запрос, а как оказывается поместить его на сайт невозможно. Идеально было бы сделать все своими ручками, думаю вы будете более компетентны в том, как это можно реализовать

@Grundy исправил

@noname в данной реализации вы уже зависите от гугла, да в любой другой реализации вы всегда будете зависеть от источника данных о курсах, так что идея непонятная

скриншот с ошибкой старой остался. Сейчас есть ошибки? или ничего не происходит?

@andreymal соглашусь, вернее будет сказать, чтобы этот скрипт работал "без выходных", чтобы он работал всегда и всегда исправно. Уж не знаю на сколько это возможно, извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но я хотел бы узнать. Получится ли сделать так, чтобы источник не замечал, что он используется на сторонних ресурсах, или он и так не замечат?

@noname надо не "чтобы источник не замечал", а найти такой источник, который разрешает к себе запросы со сторонних сайтов (такие наверняка существуют, но я ещё не пробовал искать)

@Grundy ошибки пропали, спасибо, про скриншот забыл, но как и раньше сам скрипт не ворк

@andreymal, хм.. мне казалось, что где-то видел, что появилась возможность получить ответ на анонимный запрос, но сейчас не смог. Возможно, я что-то попутал...

Ну в общем вот например Coingecko предоставляет публичный API (у бесплатного есть ограничения, но возможно они не проблема), и с его помощью простейшая javascript-реализация идеи поместится даже в этот комментарий — (async () => {let r = await fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&precision=2&vs_currencies=usd,rub'); let data = await r.json(); alert(`Один бетховен это ${data.bitcoin.usd} долларов и ${data.bitcoin.rub} рублей`)})()
